# Can't Run COD4 On Different Partition 16.04 [SOLVED]

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wine, games, ssd

I have an SSD. I had copied the entire game folder from my previous windows install onto said SSD and played COD4 on wine with no problems. I had to get win 10 for some reason(/dev/sda3), so I backed up the game folder onto my external HDD, and formatted my SSD (minus /dev/sda1, which is home). The allocation is as follows:

https://i.imgtc.com/vYI4kHR.png

Now, I can run the game on wine from the external HDD which I had backed up into, albeit loading times are slow  (as expected). I copied the entire game folder onto my newly formatted ext4 partition seen in the above ss (/dev/sda6), but when I try to run the game (multiplayer, iw3mp.exe), I get the following errors in succession:

WIN_IMPROPER_QUIT_BODY

https://imgtc.com/7wQsJq8

Error during initialization: No IWD files found in /main

https://imgtc.com/gL7UxRo

When I run the single player exe (iw3sp.exe) I get the error below instead of error2:

https://imgtc.com/V2Edwzb

I can't say this is the first problem I've had on wine, but this is probably the first time I've been unable to do anything about it. Any help is most appreciated !

**EDIT: I figured it out.** (after a lengthy search)

In winecfg under the drives tab, you have to add the drive manually. My drive was within somewhere like Media/deniz/drivename; when I used autodetect, the parent would show up as D: . In D: , you have Media/deniz/drivename as a subdirectory. You have to navigate to that, choose it and click add and then apply.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In winecfg under the drives tab, you have to add the drive manually. My drive was within somewhere like Media/deniz/drivename; when I used autodetect, the parent would show up as D: . In D: , you have Media/deniz/drivename as a subdirectory. You have to navigate to that, choose it and click add and then apply.